# How to stream Apache Arrow RecordBatches in C?

Tags: c, stream, apache-arrow

I read some data from a PostgreSQL database, convert it into RecordBatches and try to send the data to a client. But I fail to properly understand the usage of Apache Arrow C/GLib.

My information sources are the [C++ docs](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/index.html), [the Apache Arrow C/GLib reference manual](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/c_glib/arrow-glib/) and [the C/GLib Github files](https://github.com/apache/arrow/tree/master/c_glib).

By following the usage description of Apache Arrow C++ and experimenting with the wrapper classes in C, I build this minimal example of writing out a RecordBatch into a buffer and (after theoretically sending and receiving the buffer) trying to read that buffer back into a RecordBatch. But it fails and i would be glad, if you could point out my mistakes!

I omitted the error catching for readability. The code errors out at creation of the GArrowRecordBatchStreamReader. If i use the arrowbuffer or the buffer from the top in creating the InputStream, the error reads `[record-batch-stream-reader][open]: IOError: Expected IPC message of type schema but got record batch`. If i use the testBuffer the error complains about an invalid IPC stream, so the data is just corrupt.

```
void testRecordbatchStream(GArrowRecordBatch *rb){
    GError *error = NULL;

    // Write Recordbatch
    GArrowResizableBuffer *buffer = garrow_resizable_buffer_new(300, &error);
    GArrowBufferOutputStream *bufferStream = garrow_buffer_output_stream_new(buffer);
    long written = garrow_output_stream_write_record_batch(GARROW_OUTPUT_STREAM(bufferStream), rb, NULL, &error);

    // Use buffer as plain bytes
    void *data = garrow_buffer_get_data(GARROW_BUFFER(buffer));
    size_t length = garrow_buffer_get_size(GARROW_BUFFER(buffer));

    // Read plain bytes and test serialize function
    GArrowBuffer *testBuffer = garrow_buffer_new(data, length);
    GArrowBuffer *arrowbuffer = garrow_record_batch_serialize(rb, NULL, &error);

    // Read RecordBatch from buffer
    GArrowBufferInputStream *inputStream = garrow_buffer_input_stream_new(arrowbuffer);
    GArrowRecordBatchStreamReader *sr = garrow_record_batch_stream_reader_new(GARROW_INPUT_STREAM(inputStream), &error);
    GArrowRecordBatch *rb2 = garrow_record_batch_reader_read_next(sr, &error);


    printf("Received RB: \n%s\n", garrow_record_batch_to_string(rb2, &error));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my solution was to use the class GArrowRecordBatchStreamWriter and Reader, instead of the function garrow_output_stream_write_record_batch(), because the latter only writes a record batch without a stream header and schema. Furthermore one has to properly access the data of the GArrowBuffer after writing. (Again, error handling omitted)

```
    GError *error = NULL;

    GArrowResizableBuffer *buffer = garrow_resizable_buffer_new(4096, &error);

    GArrowBufferOutputStream *bufferStream = garrow_buffer_output_stream_new(buffer);
    GArrowSchema *schema = garrow_record_batch_get_schema(recordbatch);
    GArrowRecordBatchStreamWriter *sw = garrow_record_batch_stream_writer_new(GARROW_OUTPUT_STREAM(bufferStream), schema, &error);

    g_object_unref(bufferStream);
    g_object_unref(schema);

    gboolean test = garrow_record_batch_writer_write_record_batch(GARROW_RECORD_BATCH_WRITER(sw), recordbatch, &error);

    GBytes *data = garrow_buffer_get_data(GARROW_BUFFER(buffer));
    gint64 length = garrow_buffer_get_size(GARROW_BUFFER(buffer));

    gsize datasize;
    gconstpointer datap = g_bytes_get_data(data, &datasize);

    GArrowBuffer *receivingBuffer = garrow_buffer_new(datap, datasize);

    GArrowBufferInputStream *inputStream = garrow_buffer_input_stream_new(GARROW_BUFFER(receivingBuffer));
    GArrowRecordBatchStreamReader *sr = garrow_record_batch_stream_reader_new(GARROW_INPUT_STREAM(inputStream), &error);

    printf("Reading RecordBatch:\n");
    GArrowRecordBatch *recordbatch2 = garrow_record_batch_reader_read_next(GARROW_RECORD_BATCH_READER(sr), &error);
    printf("%s\n", garrow_record_batch_to_string(recordbatch2, &error));
```